# Can someone point me to the reason this constructor is being called twice?

Tags: python, function, constructor, kivy

I've noticed that the code prints the date twice to the constructor and am having trouble understanding why since I believe I only instantiate the object once within my code.

This is the constructor

```
def __init__(self):
        self.today = date.today()
        print(self.today)
```

Here is where I instantiate it

```
self.data = database()
self.schedule_today = self.data.get_bulletin()
```

Full code for this section of the program with some unfinished functions

```
class database:

    sch_today = ['apt: 8:00', "breakfast", "music", 'apt: 9:00', "therapy", 'apt: 12:00', "lunch"]
    test_schedule = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.today = date.today()
        print(self.today)

    def get_parse_bulletin_list(self):
        temp = []
        index = 0
        for i in self.sch_today:
            if i[0:3] == 'apt':
                while index%3 != 0:
                    temp.append('')
                    index+=1
                temp.append(i)
            else:
                temp.append(i)
            index += 1
        return temp

    def get_bulletin(self):
        n_count = 1
        temp = []
        ref = self.get_parse_bulletin_list()
        for i in ref:
            if i[0:3] == 'apt':
                temp.append(paper_scrap().get_layout())
                n_count = 1
            elif not i:
                temp.append(Notecard().blank_layout())
            #elif i[0:5] == '[hlf]':
                #temp.append(Notecard())
            elif n_count >= 3: #allign left
                temp.append(Notecard())
            else:
                temp.append(Notecard())
                n_count += 1
        return temp

    def update_schedule(self):
        with open('calendar.txt') as r:
            pass

class BulletinInterface(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BulletinInterface, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = database()
        self.schedule_today = self.data.get_bulletin()

        self.l1 = BulletinArea(size_hint=(1,1),
                          padding=(38, 135, 37, 34),
                          orientation=('tb-lr'))
        self.add_widget(self.l1)

        self.b1 = Button(text="test",
                         background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                         size_hint=(0.1, 0.1)
                         )
        self.b1.bind(on_press=self.bulletin_init)
        self.add_widget(self.b1)

        # bulletin board initialize
        self.bulletin_init()


    def bulletin_init(self, touch=None):
        self.init_bulletin(self.schedule_today)

    def init_bulletin(self, element_list):
        for i in element_list:
            self.l1.add_widget(i)
```

Comment: But, how many times do you instantiate `BulletinInterface`?

Comment: @quamrana I believe only once when I run the build class. However, the class seems to be instantiated twice and I can't seem to figure out why. I'll review my code some more

Comment: and if you change the print to: `print(self.today, id(self))` you still get two printouts, but now with two different ids?

Comment: @quamrana yes two different IDs are printed

Comment: Ok, are you using `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @quamrana No, I am not

Comment: Ok, please update your code with the code which instantiates `BulletinInterface`.

Comment: @quamrana done, it is at the bottom

Comment: Well, you are just going to have to debug this yourself. Can you set a breakpoint when it prints today?

Comment: @quamrana found the issue. Kivy uses a CSS type language and I was building the GUI twice using both python and the KV language haha. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem after reviewing the construction of the GUI. The KV language and regular python code were both instantiating the GUI, leading to duplicate function calls for everything.